# CADENCE spectre input format (section and library keywords)

Tags: cadence, netlist

I figured out how sections are referenced -- by specifying a section at the end of an include statement:

```
include "fileName" section=sectionName
```

My guess is that this filters in, everything enclosed by

```
section sectionName
endsection sectionName
```

What I've not found is how libraries are being referenced. By libraries I mean parts of an include file enclosed in

```
library libraryName
endlibrary libraryName
```

And there is still the little matter of nested sections or libraries.
Is this legal?
Can only the outermost section/library be referenced (peeled away)?